Hide top bar Glitch after full-screening Vs-code
I installed hide top bar and it worked perfectly until i opened Vs-code and tried to see the dock and top bar, after the extension installation both the dock and top bar were not properly working or displaying

Please add a picture if if you can, thanks

when i hover to the edge of the screen or the dock it, it shows for a millisecond then hides and then again shows for a millisecond and so on ,

this only happens with the apps that i have installed like vscode, vlc not with the system apps
it only happens when i preview the specific apps in full-screen or maximize them

Ok what version of ubuntu are you running? 22.04? 24.04? or maybe an older version 16.04? Please tell us, as if your running an older version it may be fixed

Same kind of problem , I upgraded my ubuntu system to 24.04 and a lot of things are messed up , my apache server , my mysql and phpmyadmin , the Hide Top bar extention too , In my case the top bar kind of disappears for a sec when It activates on mouse hover or even a shortcut key

I have solved the issue somehow:
The problem is, if you have set hide for both the dock and the top bar then there will be a glitch, like the one you said, this glitch will be for custom installed apps not the built in ones.
In-order to solve the problem you need to unhide one of them, either the dock or the top bar, as of mine when i unhide the dock permanently then the issue resolved.

Installing this gnome extension has solved my problem on Ubuntu 24.
Original Discussion
